# How to save infos as Json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdata

I have some infos to show in couple of labels on the screen such as time, coordinate of buttons, total video record time..
Instead of showing some infos in a label? How to save these infos locally in memory using maybe a json file?

```
- (IBAction)firstButton:(UIButton *)sender {
sender.selected  = !sender.selected;
[self starting];
[self allButtonsSelected];

_startTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(firtBtnCount)
                                             userInfo:nil
                                              repeats:YES];

self.lblForInfo.text = NSStringFromCGRect(_firstButton.frame);
NSLog(@"STOP RECORDING");
    [_startTimer invalidate];
```

Comment: Are you trying to save information so you can retrieve it next time the app is open or just in that viewcontroller?

Comment: Also instead of using lots of labels to show infos for my app, can i use just one text view to show all infos in one place?

Comment: You can do it both ways just depends how you want to organize the information and position of the data on the screen.

Comment: When i click the buttons im getting some infos about that buttons such as coordinates.Is there any way to save these infos in one textfield and save it locally like Json data.. Like this..{   "totalFrames" : 120,
    "nodes" : 
    [
        {
            "x":"x0",
            "y":"y0",
            "frame":12
        },
        {
            "x":"x1",
            "y":"y1",
            "frame":24    
        },
        {
            "x":"x2",
            "y":"y2",
            "frame":36
        },
        {
            "x":"x4",
            "y":"y4",
            "frame":48    
        }
    ]
}

Comment: You can use NSMutableDictionary to save all this data in memory.  Let me know if you want to see an example of that.  You can then store that information in NSUserDefaults if you want to access next time you run an app

Comment: If you can share an example with me. It would be great. I havent worked with any of these before.. So please share. Thank you. @Yan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
NSMutableArray *dicArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[dicArray addObject:@{@"frame":NSStringFromCGRect(button1.frame)}];
[dicArray addObject:@{@"frame":NSStringFromCGRect(button2.frame)}];
[dicArray addObject:@{@"frame":NSStringFromCGRect(button3.frame)}];
[dicArray addObject:@{@"frame":NSStringFromCGRect(button4.frame)}];
[dicArray addObject:@{@"frame":NSStringFromCGRect(button5.frame)}];

NSLog(@"dicArray:%@",dicArray);

NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dicArray options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSArray *retDicArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSLog(@"retDicArray:%@",retDicArray);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answer.. Can i create a method to show all button infos to save them locally in memory? Because i am doing the same things for 4 differents buttons. They ve got all different coordinates.. ?

Comment: json can  have the data as Dictionary formate or NSArray fromate. so , in your case you need  to have a NSArray formate of your button conordinates

Comment: can you give me an example for it please?

Comment: let me some  a few mins to do a method of creating this json dynamically

Comment: you can do simply add you dictionary into an array

Comment: Just one more question about arrays.. Do we have any chance to group infos such as ..{   "totalFrames" : 120,
    "nodes" : 
    [
        {
            "x":"x0",
            "y":"y0",
            "frame":12
        },
        {
            "x":"x1",
            "y":"y1",
            "frame":24    
        },
        {
            "x":"x2",
            "y":"y2",
            "frame":36
        },
        {
            "x":"x4",
            "y":"y4",
            "frame":48    
        }
    ]
}

Comment: no, you need not do  totalFrames and node you can just do all things from your NSArray of dictionary

Comment: totalFrames =  retDicArray.count

Comment: CGRect frame = CGRectFromString([retDicArray[0] valueForKey:@"frame"]);

Comment: NSLog(@"frame:%f,%f,%f,%f",frame.origin.x,frame.origin.y,frame.size.width,frame.size.height);